# Multiplication of functions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's assume we have defined two functions f(x) and g(x) in Python.
For each x, like x = 7, h = f(7) * g(7) is a number.

However, if we attempt to assign the function h = f * g of the type

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'function'

My question is: Why is it not trivial in Python to do such an operation (from the point of view of how Python works)? Surely, in many situations, given two functions, we'd like to be able to manipulate the function that gives their point wise product?

Or is it simply that such cases never occur? Indeed, we could readily define the function f(x)*g(x).

Comment: It does not make any sense to multiply functions. Functions are objects. What does `object * object` mean? You want to multiply the return values of the functions. The two statements are not equivalent

Comment: Agree with @DeepSpace on this. You will have better luck creating a new function / lambda that multiplies the result of evaluating the two functions.

Comment: Because Python is a programming language, not a mathematical abstraction

Comment: @DeepSpace It would be perfectly reasonable to define `f * g` as `lambda x: f(x) * g(x)`. However, it would also be perfectly reasonable to define `f * g` as the [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) of the two functions. Also, Python are also much more general than mathematical functions, and you'll quickly run into issues of how to define the product of functions with "incompatible" calling signatures. (What's the product of a 2-argument function and a 1-argument function? What about conflicting uses of the same keyword argument? etc)

Comment: @chepner Python does not deal with only numbers. What would `f * g` mean in case `f` is `insert_to_db` and `g` is `make_coffie`? IMHO function-level operators are too ambiguous and abstract. That's what I meant by "not making any sense"

Comment: Yes, but even (to play devil's advocate) if you could assume numerically valued functions (or even distinguish subtypes of functions), there are still problems in defining the product. We agree on that point. Python already has (at least) one non-numeric definition of `*`, so it *could* make sense to define the product of a function that always returns a (non-negative) integer and a function that always returns a string, for example.

Answer (score 3):

> Or is it simply that such cases never occur? Indeed, we could readily
>   define the function `f(x)*g(x)`.

You are right. There *should* only be one way of doing something, and that one way is defining a new function. As an aside, the notation `f * g` is ambiguous as, in many contexts, it represents function composition, i.e. `f(g(x))`.

Comment: What contexts? The usual operator for composition is `∘`, although that (like all Unicode characters) is not a recognized operator in Python. `*` *could* be considered an ASCII replacement, but as it is *not* used as such in Python, it's a stretch to call it "ambiguous".

Comment: IMO, the biggest hurdle to supporting function-level operators in Python is defining their semantics for functions in general. `h(x) = f(x) * g(x)` is fine if `f` and `g` take a single parameter, but what should `f * g` mean if `f` takes two arguments and `g` takes one? What if `f` and `g` both accept a keyword argument named `foo`, but `f` expects it to be an integer and `g` expects it to be a tuple? Lots of nice mathematical concepts fall apart when you try to apply them to Python's function model.

Comment: @chepner, In the context of writing mathematics, by hand, old school. Just because code vs written convention breaks down elsewhere doesn't *justify* being ambiguous here, that's a false argument. I'm only talking about this specific case.